# WDIO 5 : Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I have a webdriverio test framework with maxInstance of the browser set to 10. 
When I run my script, I get the below error message

> [local-test] (node:20572) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible
>   EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use
>   emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

How can I get this fixed? I read some information online that I can suppress this warning by either process.setMaxListeners(10);
 or emitter.setMaxListeners(10) adding to the wdio.conf.js file;

But none of the fixed the issue. Also I do not want to suppress the warning and want to see if there is a way to do a clean fix? Kindly let me know.

PS : Its webdriverio / Mocha driven test automation framework and there is no database involved. Also I googled similar answers and it did not help.

Comment: Have you created a ticket on the webdriverio github? I can reproduce this - but I also don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

please refer this [Node js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_getmaxlisteners) where it says under EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners

`The EventEmitter instance will allow more listeners to be added but will output a trace warning to stderr indicating that a "possible EventEmitter memory leak" has been detected.`

It means we will get the warning message for such scenarios